# How to wildcard aws lambda function permission in resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

Hi I have a lot of lambda functions that needs `lambda:UpdateFunctionCode` permission. Its too troublesome to input all the functions' ARNs in the resource field. All my functions has a prefix, when I try to use `prefix*` in the resource field it does not allow me.

This is what I tried but didn't work.

```
"arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:xxxxxxxx:function:prefix*"
```

Is there a way I can use a wildcard for this?

Edit: added a fake account number.

Comment: Is the account number not needed in this type of ARN?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I just did not include the account number when i put the permission here.

Comment: You say it didn't work.  Could the missing account number be the reason?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I meant in my IAM I put the account number but here in stackoverflow I remove it.

Comment: Ah. Now I see what you mean.  It isn't clear why that would not work. But `...:function:*` does work?

Comment: That's not how we want it but anyways I tried it that way and it still is not allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this is a good feature to have but I have verified with AWS support

(1) Function name format cannot include "*" (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_AddPermission.html#SSS-AddPermission-request-FunctionName)

(2) they have submit a feature request internally. The support also suggest you could also raise the concerns on the Github[3][4] page so that the Quickstart team can directly address them.

[3] https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#resource-types

[4] https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues